# On-the-fly thumbnails PHP

Tags: php, image-processing, image-manipulation, on-the-fly

I came up with this:

```
<?php 

$dir = $_GET['dir'];

header('Content-type: image/jpeg'); 

$create = imagecreatetruecolor(150, 150); 
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg($dir); 
imagecopyresampled($create, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, 150, 150, 150, 150); 

imagejpeg($create, null, 100); 

?>
```

It works by accessing:

> http://example.com/image.php?dir=thisistheimage.jpg

Which works fine... but the output is awful:

[image]

Can someone fix my code for the image to be 150 x 150 covering the black area...

Thanks.

**SOLUTION:**

```
<?php 

$dir = $_GET['dir'];

header('Content-type: image/jpeg'); 

list($width, $height) = getimagesize($dir);

$create = imagecreatetruecolor(150, 150); 
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg($dir); 

$newwidth = 150;
$newheight = 150;

imagecopyresized($create, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

imagejpeg($create, null, 100); 

?>
```

Comment: You could also use .htaccess to rewrite URL and have paths like: http://domain.com/imagephp/thisistheimage.jpg

Comment: You should save a copy of the resized image with the width/height parameters in the filename and check if it exists before processing and serve that one so that you keep the load on the server down. Also use imagedestroy($create) after imagejpeg() to free up memory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`imagecopyresized`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php):

```
$newwidth = 150;
$newheight = 150;
imagecopyresized($create, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $oldwidth, $oldheight);
```

Comment: What are the definitions of $oldwidth and $oldheight?

Comment: Ah yes of course, sorted it out now, added the solution in the edited post :)

Comment: No need to add the solution to the post, recommend you remove it.

Answer (score 1):

The last 2 `150` should be the original width and height of the full sized image.

Comment: Better left as a comment. This isn't an answer.

Comment: It was a perfectly correct answer on the ORIGINAL unmodified question.

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to undo the down vote but it says it's locked. Still, it's a lazy answer, you should probably delete it.

Comment: It's ok I don't care about the vote down. What makes it a lazy answer, that I didn't write/correct the code for him myself? I don't think that would have helped him at all, yes it would have *worked* but would he have learned what the problem was? I prefer to give gentle pushes in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

As others suggested, last two parameters should be original size of the image.

If $dir is your filename, you can use [getimagesize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) to obtain picture's original dimensions.

You can use imagecopyresized or imagecopyresampled. Difference is that imagecopyresized will copy and resize while imagecopyresampled will also resample your image which will yield better quality.

```
<?php 

$dir = $_GET['dir'];

header('Content-type: image/jpeg'); 

$create = imagecreatetruecolor(150, 150); 
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg($dir);
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($dir);
imagecopyresampled($create, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, 150, 150, $width, $height);

imagejpeg($create, null, 100); 

?>
```